# I want to get a count when a letter is added?

Tags: android

```
TextWatcher myTextWathcer = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
        TVinput.setText("Not Enetered");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
        Toast.makeText(Display.this, "YOU PRESSED ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("HEY", "You pressed ");
        countForEachLetter++;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
        if(s.length()==0)
            TVinput.setText("Not Enetered");
        else if (s.length()>0 && s.length()<6)
            TVinput.setText("Please complete fully");
    }
    settings.addTextChangedListener(myTextWathcer);
}
```

I am using a text watcher to check changes to the editText and I want show a toast for every letter added or deleted and also get a count where I use countForEachLetter (a float value) but I always get zero as the answer ?

Comment: onTextChanged() will be called for every change in edittext..it can be addition or deletion. But you are increasing the counter irrespective of it. Have a condition to know if it is only addition like if (s.length() > countForEachLetter) and increment if it is true.

Comment: How many times does LOGCAT show this command : Log.d("HEY", "You pressed ");

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
private TextView mTextView;
private EditText mEditText;
private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           //This sets a textview to the current length
           mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
};
```

and set textwatcher  as below

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue where in the next class where i am passing the value i had used different strings values in the intent i am using to pass and , and this method is working fine :D